# Is it possible to wrap text in an input?

Tags: css, html

No - I don't want to use a textarea.

I want to style an text input to basically look like a textarea. Thus I want it to break text instead of extend horizontally.

Why? I want to disallow line breaks in user input and I want to avoid to implement javascript which disallows <kbd>return</kbd>, removing line breaks from pasted content and other possible *hacks*.

Comment: not sure how to get the text to align to the top -- https://jsfiddle.net/teqs6dov/

Comment: you can create a custom element and extend it to have the input functionality -- http://webcomponents.org/articles/introduction-to-custom-elements/

Comment: Sure we could extend elements to do what should be common behavior. But then again, why isn't what should be common behavior something we have to re-invent every time we want to do it? System Failure.

Comment: According to spec, you cannot, but you could build something _like_ it using [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. It is not possible to wrap text in an input as a standard feature.

If you manage to hack it, that would be invalid HTML.

*HTML5 spec:*

> [**4.10.5.1.2 Text (`type=text`) state and Search state
>   (`type=search`)**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#text-typetext-state-and-search-state-typesearch)
>
> The `input` element represents a ***one line*** plain text edit
>   control for the element's value.
>
> *(emphasis mine)*

Comment: You cannot get apples from people who think apples are oranges. One line does not mean the text cannot wrap, and the fact that the input control does not support wrapped single line text (as you claim it would be invalid) is an invalid assumption. Multi-line means with line feed characters, and single line actually means no line characters. So in effect, the guy asks for apples and everybody hands him oranges.

Comment: Please don't use my claim as a basis for your comment. Use the official reference, which simply and clearly states: ***"...one line plain text..."***. You really can't get around that, as far as I can tell. But if you want to provide an official reference for the definition of "one line", which supports the claim in your comments, please go ahead. That would actually be useful and more helpful than simple criticism and a downvote. @HypersoftSystems

Answer (score -6):

First off, you might want to use a `textarea` anyway - `input` was not designed for this.

You can still achieve the desired effect with css.

```css
input {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-word;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="This line wraps because it is quite long."/>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hfvga3cd/

Comment: I started my question with ` No - I don't want to use an textarea.` and you recommend using a textarea? Anyway. Your fiddle is not working

Comment: @Brettetete With what did you check that fiddle? .. I tried and it works perfect.

Comment: I just tested it in other browsers - it's working fine in Chrome, but not in Firefox, Edge and IE. So not really an option for serious web development.

Comment: I tested too, too bad not cross browser

Comment: delete the text and start typing -- the text is in the middle. can you fix that so it starts from the top

Comment: Apparently it stopped working starting on Chrome 50. :(